# I would like to know why I’m not getting IBOutlets connected in an App’s window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xib, iboutlet

The results are pretty easy to replicate.

1. Create a new Xcode project called TestWindow.
2. XIB not storyboard.
3. Objective-C
4. Set the project’s scheme to turn off Metal API validation.
5. Set Build Options to NO ARC under Objective-C options.
6. Delete the Main Menu window.
7. Create a new window object called GoWindow. And add a window to it.
8. Set File’s Owner of the AppDelegate object in Placeholders to AppDelegate.
9. Drag a Scrollable Text View from the Library to the Window
10. Connect an IBOutlet NSWindow in AppDelegate to the window.
11. Connect an IBOutlet NSScrollview in AppDelegate to the scrollview in the window.
12. Connect an IBOutlet NSTextView in AppDelegate to the textView in the ScrollView in the window.
13. In AppDelegate, create an IBAction method to makeWindow.
14. Add a menu item called makeWindow to the AppDelegate.
15. Wire the menu item to the IBAction in AppDelegate.
16. Create a method in AppDelegate called `makeWindowContinued`.
17. Add a breakpoint to an `NSBeep();` inside the `makeWindowContinued` method.
18. Add `[self performSelector:@selector(makeGoWindowContinued) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];`  to the AppDelegate method.
19. Run the app.
20. The breakpoint will trigger allowing you to see that the three outlets and not being set.
21. Here is the resultant AppDelegate.h code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSWindow           *theDocumentWindow;
    IBOutlet NSScrollView       *theDocumentWindowScrollView;
    IBOutlet NSTextView         *theDocumentWindowTextView;

    NSWindowController          *myDocumentWindowController;
    
}

- (NSWindowController *)myDocumentWindowController ;
- (void)set_myDocumentWindowController:(NSWindowController *)t;
- (IBAction)makeWindow:(id)sender;
- (void)makeGoWindowContinued;

@end
```

And the resultant AppDelegate.m code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (NSWindowController *)myDocumentWindowController                                   {return myDocumentWindowController;}
- (void)set_myDocumentWindowController:(NSWindowController *)t                        {[t retain];    [myDocumentWindowController release];                    myDocumentWindowController = t;}

- (IBAction)makeWindow:(id)sender
{
    if (![self myDocumentWindowController]) {
        [self set_myDocumentWindowController:[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"GoWindow"]];
    }
    [[[self myDocumentWindowController] window] setTitleWithRepresentedFilename:@"Untitled"];
    [[[self myDocumentWindowController] window] center];
    [[[self myDocumentWindowController] window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [self performSelector:@selector(makeGoWindowContinued) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; // wait for window to appear
}

- (void)makeGoWindowContinued
{
    NSBeep();
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (BOOL)applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState:(NSApplication *)app
{
    return YES;
}
```

I'm not sure File's Owner is correct, maybe I need to set a delegate? Don't know.

Comment: Can you please format your code blocks. Right now it’s a mulch of bullet points and code.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the question's text from Notes. Didn't know how to format but it seems to be right now, above.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I'm sorry but I don't understand steps 7 and 8. Add a window to a window? What is "File’s Owner of the AppDelegate object in Placeholders"?

Comment: Step 7 creates a window object with a window in it. That window will have a scrollView in it. Step 8 sets the File's Owner to App Delegate, I also tried setting File's Owner to NSApplication, No luck. The AppDelegate files (.h and .m) were created by Xcode when the project was created. The object of the question is to find out why the IBOutles are still nil when the breakpoint occurs. The window has had plenty of time to load.

Comment: Is a window object a xib file? If a window has a window controller then usually the window controller owns the window, is the file's owner, is the window's delegate and has the outlets to the controls in the window. The app delegate talks to the window controller, not to the window or the controls. The window controller controls the window.

Comment: If you want the app delegate to be the file's owner then use `[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"GoWindow" owner:self]`. Be aware of dangling pointers when you close the window.

Comment: So the window I put in the XIB is redundant? How do I get IBOutlets into a window created by a window controller?

Comment: I think that is what I did in the MakeWindow method.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Which object owns the window? Why do you use a `NSWindowController`? Why is the window in a new xib instead of MainMenu.xib? Do you instantiate the window once? When do you want to use the outlets?

Comment: AppDelegate owns the window. Because WindowControllers make new windows from nibs. Because this is a demo program that illustrates that my outlets are not being connected. In reality, I have a huge program that is having the same problem but can't be replicated here because it's too large. MainMenu is used for other things. I think I instantiate only once, follow the steps in my original question. ai want to use the outlets right after the NSBeep() but they are always nil.

Comment: Have you tried `[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"GoWindow" owner:self]`? The File's Owner class is `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Willeke, I have restructured my program to eliminate using WindowControllers and instead use windows defined in MainMenu. Seems to work as expected now. I'm very grateful for your suggestion, I had so presumed that WindowControllers were the right way to go that I hadn't considered another entirely different approach. I guess that sometimes you get too close to the problem and don't see an alternative. I very much appreciate your involvement and suggestions, they forced me into a different solution.